# c#/LINQ to SQL insertonsubmit() doesnt work

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have problem with my desktop application in c#. I decided to migrate my very simple web application in web forms to windows forms. I used sql and LINQ. In web forms everything worked fine. Now in windows forms no. Code is exactly the same. I change it to only one control and one table in database. I debbuged and i think everything is fine but from some reason insertonsubmit() command doesnt work. I will be grateful for help.

I use Windows 8, Visual for web 2012, for desktop 2013

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        osoba obj = new osoba();

        obj.nazwa ="Anna";

        db.osobas.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    }
}
```

in attachment project:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nHhrRU4CjHZExDMFRlNkZzN0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code will work in pricnipe. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? That is not an intelligent description of an error.

Comment: I dont have any errors but table is empty. I suppose there is something wrong with insertonsubmit() but i don't know how to find error

Comment: What's the connection string in app.config?

Comment: `code`connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\baza.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"`code`

In the link there is a full project. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Entity Framework just try this:

```
obj.nazwa ="Anna";

db.SaveChanges();
```